# Series of cicles with stroke-dasharray are unhramonious, either canvas or svg

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, graphics

I want to draw a series of circles which share a common center point, and every circle's path shall be dashed.I've tried in canvas or svg, Like below

```js
// svg.datum(d3.range(40)).enter().append('g')
var w = window.innerWidth,
    h = window.innerHeight;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

// svg.append("rect")
//     .attr("width", w)
//     .attr("height", h);
var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
    .data(d3.range(35,60))
    // .data([25])
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")")
    // .attr("transform", "rotate(-10," + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")" )
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", "5%")                                        
    // .attr("stroke-dashoffset", "15")                                        
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d * 5; });

svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
    .data(d3.range(25,35))
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", "10")                                        
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")")
    .attr("class", "salmon")                                        
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d * 5; });
```

```css
body{
 /*background: salmon;*/
 /*color: #fff;*/
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

canvas{
 /*background: #ccc;*/
}

svg{
 /*background: rgba(46,139,87,0.5);*/
 background: #fff;
}

rect {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: rgba(46,139,87,0.5);
}

.salmon{
 stroke: salmon;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.4.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```

```
https://jsfiddle.net/fanyer/kcwL3vwc/
```

A white line which is scaled up by series of circles between open neighborhood below the baseline where it's draw  at first.

is there any solution to eliminate the nonuniform?

Comment: make sure the sum of the stroke-dasharray values divide the circle circumference.

Comment: I've set strokeDashLine [5%,5%]. I think there is no doubt about the division proportion.

Comment: That's 5% of the viewBox size, it has nothing at all to do with the circle circumference.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that it starts to draw from a certain postion.

For svg , its [reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG-access/) indicates that its start is 3 o'clock.

For canvas, its [reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/), its 2d context starts from 12 o'clock.

Answer (score -1):

I'm the asker. I've look up svg and webgl in both mdn and msdn, with opengl b except directX docs. Seems it must determine a baseline to draw graphics. As a result there is no problem under much occasions but for one or more.

That is series of dashed graphics which is proportion with each other. This will blow up the badness to the degrees people can see it out.Even though there is one curve, the problem also exists and cannot be felt.  A typical case is that many stroke-dashed circles which shares the same centre point.

In my opion, it should be equal to the probelm that Computer or the system graphic library cannot figure out a true Fraction but Decimal representation

Comment: Do you feel this answers your question? It doesn't seem to to me. If this is merely further information about your question you should edit it into the question and delete this answer.